# WinMerge Binary Difference

Tags: file-corruption, binary-files, winmerge

So I'm trying to manually RAID all of my important data obtained through life, and have just discovered the joys of WinMerge to compare & identify differences between files & directories. However a load of files have been flagged to my attention as 'Binary files are different'...

Opening both files for observation appears to demonstrate identical copies, and at some point in history they were the same file, 1 being copied to another location, just as is about to happen again right now in my manual RAID copying routine...

So are we saying here that 1 of those files has become corrupted sitting on the hard drive since it was copied to it's new location (or the old one residing in original location)? And if so, then which one is the corrupted one? All I can see is that there is some difference at the binary level, but which one is the original intact file free of all corruption?

How can I be sure that I am not going to delete the 'perfect' version and instead make multiple copies of a corrupted file?

Thanks for any deep routed insight that could help me expose these binary corruptions

Comment: *"But which one is the original intact file free of all corruption?"* - You probably can't know this without hashes of the "original" file (i.e. made before any changes took place). It's also worth noting that this could also simply be different versions of the same file (for instance, an updated `.exe` or `.dll` could have the same file name, but be a different file from a binary perspective).

Comment: Thank you so much Anaksunaman, I knew some bright spark would know the answer, & makes perfect sense what you say.  I still do not know if this means that the files have just corrupted themselves sitting on the hard drive over time?  Which would be nice to know (as you say they may have been updated by new dll), but serves me right for not following due diligence protocol & taking those binary stamps from the 1st place, have I learnt my lesson?  No, I cannot be bothered, got too much else to be getting on with...